# Showing Issue with #1&#2 while passing as param

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

There is a scenario like importing data as excel and validate, then store in db.
While clicking the validate button, it shows the message validating:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '157' in

The debug point is not hitting in the server side too.

I think the issue with `JSON.stringify(columnMapping)` as it contains `HALL BY #1&#2`. If I put a space between `&` and `#`, the validating process works fine. However I need to check with the data `HALL BY #1&#2`. Can anyone help?

```js
function btnValidateClick() {
  toggleLoading(true, "Validating...");
  var url = '@Url.Action("Validate", "ImportEquipment")';
  var params = {
    columnMapping: JSON.stringify(columnMapping),
    fixedFields: fixedFields,
    nonFixedFields: NonFixedFields,
    ClassType: $("#ClassType").val(),
    taskId: $("#taskId").val(),
    selectedclassId: document.getElementById("selectedclassId").value
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: getDatawithformToken(params),
    success: function(result) {
      columnMapping = result;
      toggleLoading(false, "Validating...");
      if (($("table#tblFields .error").closest('tr').length > 0) || ($("table#tblFields .errorMessage").closest('tr').length > 0)) {
        showMessageBox("Validation completed", "wijGridView1");
      } else {
        showMessageBox("Validation Passed", "wijGridView1");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

C# server side code

```
public ActionResult Validate(string columnMapping, string fixedFields, string nonFixedFields, string ClassType, string taskId, string selectedclassId)
{
  try
  {
    // Code here...
  }
  catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: `&#` is the prefix for a HTML entity, hence the error is because the following `2` isn't a valid hex reference for an entity. To fix this you need to encode the text to `&amp;#2`. You can do this by using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). I can't give you a specific example as you've not shown how you build the `columnMapping` object, nor what its contents are.

Comment: Can you provide `getDatawithformToken()` function? I don't see any usage of `in` or `$.each()` in your code.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto function getDatawithformToken(param) {
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        $.extend(param, { '__RequestVerificationToken': token });
        return param;
    }

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan     Thanks.........  Now it is working fine  :)